# Department wise salary without using GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I need to get the desired output without using GROUP BY Clause

```
CREATE TABLE #Dept
(
    DeptName VARCHAR(30),
    Salary INT
)

INSERT INTO #Dept VALUES ('A',100),('A',90),('A',80),('A',70),('A',60),('B',80),('B',20),('B',40)
```

Expected Output:

```
DeptName   Salary
 A         400
 B         140
```

Comment: Check out: `GROUP BY` and `SUM()`.

Comment: Why are you SHOUTING?

Comment: What do you have against `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Windowed `SUM` without `ORDER BY` and `DISTINCT` will help here, but the question is why?

Comment: They asked me this question during an interview.

Comment: So what was *your* answer? It was your interview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a `Group By` ... seems like an odd requirement.

```
Select Distinct 
       DeptName
      ,Salary = sum(Salary) over (partition by DeptName) 
 From  #Dept
```

**Returns**

```
DeptName    Salary
A           400
B           140
```